# Проход по алфавиту Python

Tags: python

Можно ли как-то инкрементировать символ латинского алфавита? Нужно пройтись по алфавиту в Python, либо по числу получать какой-то определенный символ, есть такие функции?

Comment: сам новенький в питоне, но если нет то пишется ж просто a=tuple('abcdef....xyz') вместо точек вставить все буквы алфавита и получите то, что вам надо.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Получение символа по его номеру из Unicode:

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
>>> chr(122)
'z'
>>> print(chr(128522))
```

(в Python 2 лучше вместо `chr` использовать `unichr`)

Получение номера из Unicode по символу:

```
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('z')
122
>>> ord('')
128522
```

Заранее заготовленные строки с латинскими (и не только) символами есть в модуле `string`:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

По этим строкам можно проходиться циклом:

```
for c in string.ascii_letters:
    print(c)
```

Во всяких генераторных выражениях и условиях, разумеется, тоже:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'fooУБРАТЬbarОТСЮДАbazНЕЛАТИНСКОЕ'
>>> s2 = ''.join(c for c in s if c in string.ascii_letters)
>>> print(s2)
foobarbaz
```

Comment: Cпасибо, очень помогло)